# Why can a url have 301 redirect-loops without any .htaccess rules

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a redirect loop on my robots.txt file which keeps redirecting from `https://www.URL.com/robots.txt` to the same `https://www.URL.com/robots.txt`. The rest of the site - or at least what I observed so far - works perfectly fine.

In .htaccess we have some redirect rules for missing `https` or `www` in place, so at first I thought the reverse proxy might for example serve a wrong protocol, but that seems not the case. After playing around for a while, I simply did a `mv .htaccess .htacc` to completely disable all instructions. This causes all other pages to return 404 of course (page runs on wordpress), but the redirect loop on the `.robots.txt` still exists. I also added a query string `?a=b` to the curl request URL to ensure uncached results and tried some online tools to verify the redirect as well. All with the same result.

The `robots.txt` won't spin up any of the php logic and the .htaccess is disabled, so I am wondering what might still cause the 301-loop?

The server runs on docker-containers with nginx, varnish, wordpress and mariadb.

Comment: Redirect may be launched by vhosts.conf, httpd.conf at server level, instead of directory/.htaccess.